# Работа с директорией в PHP

Tags: php

У меня в папке **folder** есть картинки: *1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg...*

Мне нужно узнать "максимальное имя картинки", что бы следующую назвать *max+1*.

У меня есть это: =)

```
$d=opendir(".");
while($name = readdir($d)){
    if($name=="." or $name=="..")
    {
        continue;
    }
    echo $name."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$max = 0;

$d=opendir(".");
while($name = readdir($d)){
    if($name=="." or $name=="..")
    {
        continue;
    }
    $num = basename($name,'.jpg');
    if ($max < $num) $max=$num;
}
echo $max;
```

Comment: Большое Спасибо! все работает.

Answer (score 2):

```
$files = glob("*.jpg");
sort($files, SORT_NUMERIC);
$max = (int)basename(array_pop($files), ".jpg");
```